# ' Windows Subsystem for Linux' option not showing up in Windows Server 2016

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-server-2016

I am using Windows Edition 1607 on Windows Server 2016. I need to enable the ' Windows Subsystem for Linux'. I am unable to find this option in the Add Features option. You can view the screenshot for the same:

[image: Redirects to screenshot of Features list]

Please help me understand how to find that option. Do I need to download any additional software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSL is only available starting with Windows Server 2016 release 1803.

- https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2018/06/13/installing-wsl-on-windows-server.aspx

Officially it seems it's only supported in Windows Server 2019:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server